# Self contained http/https library

Tags: c++, c, http, https

I'm looking for a C/C++ library to get pages over http and https (possibly version 1.0 only), with the smallest number of dependencies (e.g. not libcurl), available on the major OSes (Windows, Linux, OSX). Is there such thing?

Comment: So what's wrong with curl exactly? Why not run `configure` and disable everything except what you need

Comment: You can definitely take a look at oat++(https://oatpp.io/), it was designed exactly for this use case.

Answer (score 2):

This depends a lot on your requirements. If you just need HTTP/1.0 support, without any consideration for proxies, keepalives, and all the stuff that's in HTTP/1.1 and make HTTP *difficult*, you can write an HTTP client in about 30 lines of C code. Add another 50 lines to include libssl for HTTPS. So unless you specify your requirements a bit better we can't help you.

(Besides, questions about finding a tool or library are considered off-topic here).

Comment: 1.0 is fine. I don't agree that finding libraries is off topic, it's a question that can be regarded as implementation design. And if you have some pointers on how I can implement basic https support with libssl, I could check whether it's feasible.

Comment: @LorenzoPistone I'm afraid that while you don't agree, the [site's official documentation (see point 5)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) does.